# excel のデータ分析グラフの時間の目盛を0からにする

Tags: vba, excel

csvファイルを読み込んで、データ分析を使用して、グラフを作成しているのですが、x軸の目盛を「年月日時間」表示から「分」表示にし、y軸と同じように0からにしたいのですが、
軸の書式設定ではシリアル値の関係なのかうまくいきません。

この場合はVBAや他の方法で設定をすることができるのでしょうか。

[image: グラフ]

Answer (score 1):

Excelの日付は、1900年1月1日からの経過日数を表すシリアル値です。2個の年月日時間のセルがある場合に、その差をとって、`24*60`を掛けると分の経過時間になります。シートの方で、分の経過時間を計算して、x軸を「年月日時間表示」の列（行）から「分の経過時間」の列（行）に変更すれば修正されます。

```
=(B3-B$2)*24*60
```